# Add Unique CSS to Different Array Elements

Tags: javascript, css

I've tried to look around for the past half hour but I don't believe anyone has asked this before, as I cannot find an answer. How do I specify different CSS  for each element within an array. Preferably appending a class to the array element to limit redundancy.

`var Stat = new Array();`

`Stat[0] = "<span class='good'>Alive</span>";`

In other words I want to accomplish the above.

Comment: What do you mean? Your example is not clear. Do you already have an array of HTML strings and want to do something with it, or you want to create an array? If so, based on what data?

Comment: As an aside... If you're simply trying to apply CSS to elements according to a particular index, you can try the `nth-child` pseudo-selector described here: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/. It has some compatibility issues with much older browsers, but it should work.

Comment: I think Tracy has what you need, her suggestion of the nth child css is also a route to take but that is CSS3. You can also use jquery [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)('# of element in the same level of the dom tree') to select the elements

Answer (score 1):

To populate the array with your HTML/CSS code you can do the following:

```
var Stat = new Array();

Stat.push("<span class='good'>Alive</span>");

Stat.push("<span class='bad'>Dead</span>");

Stat.push("<span class='evil'>Hell</span>");
```

After the code above your array `Stat` will have the following content:

```
Stat[0] == "<span class='good'>Alive</span>";

Stat[1] == "<span class='bad'>Dead</span>";

Stat[2] == "<span class='evil'>Hell</span>";
```

Each `push` create a new array position with a incremental index.

Hope it can help you!

Comment: Sorry everyone I'm not home right now, ill be home in an hour. I believe using stat.push will work but will it work if I do stat[0].push. once I get home I can provide you will all my souvenir code if that doesn't work.

Comment: @AdrianVona, Please see the update i've done, you will understand better.

Comment: I'll wait for a further explanation, but atm `stat[0].push()` shouldn't work because `stat[0]` isn't an array, it references an item in an array. Array.push() is an array method that will append an item to an array.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. Once I get home ill implement the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I'm understanding your question properly. You could just iterate through the array and append a class with a prefix followed by the index. Please let me know if I'm not following your question correctly.

```
var Stat = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  Stat.push('<span class="good' + i + '">Alive</span>');
}

// Produces an array with the following:
<span class="good0">Alive</span>
<span class="good1">Alive</span>
<span class="good2">Alive</span>
<span class="good3">Alive</span>
<span class="good4">Alive</span>
<span class="good5">Alive</span>
```